# Cygwin: bad reloc address linking la

Tags: python, gcc, linker, cygwin, ld

I am trying to install this [python package](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/) on my cygwin(last available version) setup, using gcc and no windows/microsoft components at all. The package has many dependencies so it can take a while for you to try to install it. I guess the error is generic and you don't require to replicate the issue to provide insights on how to fix it.

I have found this error for several(all?) .la libraries on the package:

```
Making all in centrality
make[4]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/gdrive/Thesis/tech/urv tech/graph-tool-2.2.31/src/graph/centrality'
  CXX      graph_betweenness.lo
  CXX      graph_centrality_bind.lo
  CXX      graph_closeness.lo
  CXX      graph_eigentrust.lo
  CXX      graph_eigenvector.lo
  CXX      graph_hits.lo
  CXX      graph_katz.lo
  CXX      graph_pagerank.lo
  CXX      graph_trust_transitivity.lo
  CXXLD    libgraph_tool_centrality.la
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: warning: --export-dynamic is not supported for PE targets, did you mean --export-all-symbols?
.libs/graph_betweenness.o:graph_betweenness.cc:(.text+0x182b): undefined reference to `graph_tool::GraphInterface::GetNumberOfVertices()'
.libs/graph_betweenness.o:graph_betweenness.cc:(.text+0x19bd): undefined reference to `graph_tool::GraphInterface::GetNumberOfVertices()'
.libs/graph_betweenness.o:graph_betweenness.cc:(.text+0x1a68): undefined reference to `graph_tool::ValueException::ValueException(std::string const&)'
.libs/graph_betweenness.o:graph_betweenness.cc:(.text+0x1a87): undefined reference to `graph_tool::ValueException::~ValueException()'
.libs/graph_betweenness.o:graph_betweenness.cc:(.text+0x1ad1): undefined reference to `graph_tool::ValueException::ValueException(std::string const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: .libs/graph_betweenness.o: bad reloc address 0x6 in section `.text$_ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_baseD1Ev[__ZN5boost16exception_detail10clone_baseD1Ev]'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:474: recipe for target 'libgraph_tool_centrality.la' failed
```

As I see .lo files are built, probably not correctly, and when it comes to generate the .la file is when I get the 'bad reloc address' error. In other words, my assumption is that because the .lo files are not correctly generated the .la built fails.

Doing some research I have found this bug reported and fixed back in 2009:

https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-binutils@gnu.org/msg07150.html

Based on it, I understand that an approach to try to fix the problem would be to replace the -export-dynamic flag by -export-all-symbols in the configure file the python library uses to install itself. There are two files that I modify: `configure` and `[configure.ac][2]`

Configure has this kind of export-dynamic mentions, related to other settings:

export_dynamic_flag_spec_CXX='${wl}--export-dynamic'

Configure.ac has this one only:

[MOD_LDFLAGS="-module -avoid-version -export-dynamic -no-undefined -Wl,-E -Wl,--as-needed"]

that I think is the key one because it refers to LD flags.

But if I do this, the project seems to break an I receive messages saying the files used in the build have the wrong version of libtool.

```
make[4]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/gdrive/Thesis/tech/urv tech/graph-tool-2.2.31/src/graph/centrality'
  CXX      graph_betweenness.lo
libtool: Version mismatch error.  This is libtool 2.4.2, but the
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.2
libtool: and run autoconf again.
Makefile:507: recipe for target 'graph_betweenness.lo' failed
```

There are mentions also in aclocal.m4 that if I try to change cause additional problems related to build files version.

In addition, in `ltmain.sh` it is verified for some libraries if they have been generated with the flag export-dynamic.

So, several points here:

- what is the difference between the .la and the .lo libraries that the module tries to generate?
- I think the problem is related to differences in static and dynamic link but really don't know how to fix it. Are there other settings involved?
- In general, any hints on what to try?